# Where to find the official paper for the STL-Library?

Tags: c++, stl, standards, iso, standard-library

For my bachelor thesis, I have to refer to some functionality in the STL-Library. Since cplusplus.com, or cppreference.com isn't the best way to reference to the functionalities, I am looking for the official paper for the STL-Library (somehting like the ISO C++-standard drafts respectively papers).

Comment: cppreference is quite good, actually.

Comment: @Barry I also thought that, but my supervisor recommended me, that I should use the ISO-drafts for C++-functionalities. For that reason, he might want the original papers (if they exist) for the STL-functionalities too. But since he is on vacancy, I cannot ask him.

Comment: @mbed_dev There's no official documentation for the STL. It never was "official" (from the PoV of C++, i.e. it was never standardized), and it has long been abandoned.